# Powershell Invoke-command Rename-Computer

Tags: powershell

I have am working on a GUI to rename computers and am getting a Parameter set cannot be resolved Error. Any ideas or suggestions?

The function in question is here. Full code below in case that is needed.

```
##Run Button
Function RenameComputers{
        $userPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $Password -AsPlainText -Force
        $Credential = New-Object -TypeName "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential" -ArgumentList $Username, $userPassword
        foreach ($item in $DataGrid.Items){
        $OName = $item.OldName
        $NName = $item.NewName
        $command = "Rename-Computer -ComputerName $OName -NewName $NName -DomainCredential $Credential -Force -Restart"
        Invoke-Command $command
    }
    }
```

Full code

```
#LoadForm

./LoadDialog.ps1 -XamlPath 'C:\Forms\ReNamer.xaml'

#EVENT Handler
$OldName
$NewName

$AddNameBtn.Add_Click({AddName})

$Import.Add_Click({GetCompList})
$Run.Add_Click({RenameComputers})

#Launch the window
$xamGUI.ShowDialog() | Out-Null


#Csv import button
Function GetCompList{
   $inputfile = Get-FileName "C:\Sysinternals"
   $csvfile = import-csv $inputfile |
        Select-Object @{ n = "OldName"; e = { $_.OldName } }, @{ n = "NewName"; e = { $_.NewName } }
   $csvfile | % { $dataGrid.AddChild($_) }
   }


##Function to open File Explorer dialog box.
Function Get-FileName($initialDirectory){
  try{  
  [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms") | Out-Null
    $OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
    $OpenFileDialog.initialDirectory = $initialDirectory
    $OpenFileDialog.filter = "CSV (*.csv)| *.csv"
    $OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
    $OpenFileDialog.filename
    }
    catch{
    }
}


##Run Button
Function RenameComputers{
        $userPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $Password -AsPlainText -Force
        $Credential = New-Object -TypeName "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential" -ArgumentList $Username, $userPassword
        #$creds = Get-Credential
        foreach ($item in $DataGrid.Items){
        $OName = $item.OldName
        $NName = $item.NewName
        $command = "Rename-Computer -ComputerName $OName -NewName $NName -DomainCredential $Credential -Force -Restart"
        Invoke-Command $command
    }
    }


##Add Name button
   Function AddName{
    $row = New-Object PSObject
    Add-Member -InputObject $row -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "OldName" -Value $OldName.Text
    Add-Member -InputObject $row -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "NewName" -Value $NewName.Text
    $DataGrid.AddChild($row)
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `Invoke-Command` instead of just calling `Rename-Computer` directly?

Comment: Good point. Because I am using this as a learning exercise. Thank you i removed the Invoke-Command and found a whole new set of errors. BUT it is running the command now. I tried invoke command because originally i was using a netdom command and think i needed it for that?

Comment: I've found that I _rarely_ need to use `Invoke-Command`, and I've never needed it when the command is to be executed on the local computer. Since `Rename-Computer` doesn't need to be executed on the remote computer - the existence of a `-ComputerName` parameter typically means that the cmdlet can act on a remote computer directly - `Invoke-Command` isn't needed.

Answer (score 0):

The command should be a scriptblock.  Hopefully, you aren't giving out the credentials to a domain administrator.  The user would have to be a local admin.

```
$command = {Rename-Computer -ComputerName $OName -NewName $NName -DomainCredential $Credential -Force -Restart}
Invoke-Command $command
```

For a remote computer, even if you're logged in locally as a domain admin, you still have to send the domain credential:

```
invoke-command $OName {rename-computer $using:NName -DomainCredential $using:credential}
```

Or without invoke-command:

```
rename-computer $NName -ComputerName $OName -Protocol WSMan -DomainCredential $credential
```